# Input instances are not in JSON format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm practicing GCP ML engine using Google's public templates and examples located [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/cloudml-template/examples)

After I ran the code in the example "housing-regression" **LOCALLY**, the model was successfully generated.

However, in prediction, an error was raised

> ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) Input instances are not in JSON format.
>
> See "gcloud ml-engine predict --help" for details.

The codes I ran is in `local-train.sh`

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=${MODEL_LOCATION} --json-instances=data/new-data.json
```

Does anyone have the same problem? Did I make a mistake somewhere or is there some information I may have missed?

***NOTES:***

1. This code is running locally on my Mac using GCP SDK which I have installed
2. I checked the file and it is indeed a JSON file.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? Now I am facing the same error. Can you help me to clear this error? What is the json file you have sent to do online prediction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For online prediction,  the json needs to be one instance per line. So try removing the pretty formatting ...