# Model Prediction JSON request format not working in python request: Google AI platform

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to predict the image to model deployed in Google Cloud AI platform. Followed is the request format for prediction:

`{"instances": [{"b64": "X5ad6u"}]}` //sample b64 format [instead of X5ad6u => real image value]

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request

But it's failing and providing the error as Prediction error: instances

```
{ "error": "JSON Value:  Excepting \'instances\' to be an list/array" }
```

input request format: `{"instances": [{"b64": "X5ad6u"}]}`

**python sample code:**

```
import argparse
import base64
import json
import googleapiclient.discovery
import six
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

credential_path = "sample.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"

def predict_json(project, model, instances, version=None):
    print("i am here to predict")

    # Create the ML Engine service object.
    # To authenticate set the environment variable
    # GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
    name = 'projects/myproject/models/beverage_optimizer'.format(project, model)

    if version is not None:
        name += '/versions/'.format(version)

    response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={'instances': instances}
    ).execute()

    if 'error' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

    return response['predictions']
a



def main(project, model, version=None):
    """Send user input to the prediction service."""
    print('I m in True')
    try:
        #user_input = json.loads("home/ubuntu/Hrishi/FreshnessWithUI/request.json")
        json_data=open("request.json").read()
        user_input = json.loads(json_data)
        #print(user_input)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return
    try:
        result = predict_json(project, model, user_input, version=None)
       # print(result)
    detectionscores = result['predictions'][0]['detection_scores']
    detectionboxes = result['predictions'][0]['detection_boxes']
    detectionclasses = result['predictions'][0]['detection_classes']
    #print(detectionscores)
    #print(detectionboxes)
    #print(detectionclasses)
    pre_data={}
    k=0
        for a,b,c in zip(detectionscores,detectionboxes,detectionclasses):
            if a >= 0.90:
                pre_data[k+1]={"score":a,"box":b, "class": int(c) } ;
                k=k+1;
        print("pre-data:",pre_data)
        #print("type", type(pre_data))
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print(str(err))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--project',
        help='Project in which the model is deployed',
        #type=str,
        #required=True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--model',
        help='Model name',
        #type=str,
        #required=True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--version',
        help='Name of the version.',
        #type=str
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(    
        args.project,
        args.model,
        version=args.version
    )
```

**Another Method:**

through google cloud command:
*gcloud ai-platform predict --model beverage_optimizer --version beverage_optimizer --json-instances request.json*

**Error:**  (gcloud.ai-platform.predict) Input instances are not in JSON format

Comment: We had this a while back - took a few efforts to get the incantation exactly right. Can you show the code where you save the model? As I recall we need to exactly match the `model_inputs` dictionary.

Comment: Check the edited code. model is saved in Google Cloud AI platform. Actually it is working in cloud Test console but not working through code for the same format used in test console.  https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict  @Stewart_R

Comment: Ml engine, right? But you have to save the model first and upload to GCS, no? (Or an I misunderstanding where it's stored and/or out of date on mechanism)

Comment: yes saved the model(contains pb file and variables folder). then uploaded to gcp and deployed the model. tested in model console with json data. its working there. but for the same format it is not working when i hit through python code or google ml engine predict command

Comment: This is exactly the same path I followed. I am looking for the code that saved the .pb model  - specifically the call to `tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def()` where we pass the model_inputs (or is there another mechanism you used?) For us, we needed to match the keys in the input dict when calling via API but not from gcloud console. Caused a load of confusion for us for a while. I strongly suspect you have same issue?

Comment: Suspect (though never confirmed) that gcloud app is doing some work before calling webapi endpoint leading to confusion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653384/input-instances-are-not-in-json-format. they answered like it should be in one line. i tried that too not working. do you have idea on formating that @Stewart_R

Comment: no actually i am trying to get response from gcloud only. i didn't changed anything in model inputs